Не работает поиск, пустой datagridview C++/CLI
    String^ connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0;Data Source=C://Users//loldo//Desktop//Laba2ais//FisermanParadise.accdb";
    OleDbConnection^ dbConnection = gcnew OleDbConnection(connectionString);
    dbConnection->Open();

    // Получение условия поиска (И или ИЛИ)
    String^ searchCondition = radio_btn_ILI->Checked ? " AND " : " OR ";
    String^ Query = "SELECT * FROM [FDProg] WHERE 1=1"; 

    if (!String::IsNullOrEmpty(textBox_SearchDlinaUdilisha->Text)) {
        Query += searchCondition + " Длина_удилища LIKE '*" + textBox_SearchDlinaUdilisha->Text + "*'";
    }
    if (!String::IsNullOrEmpty(textBox_SearchMaterialIsgotov->Text)) {
        Query += searchCondition + " Материал_изготовления LIKE '*" + textBox_SearchMaterialIsgotov->Text + "*'";
    }
    if (!String::IsNullOrEmpty(textBox_SearchTest->Text)) {
        Query += searchCondition + " Тест LIKE '*" + textBox_SearchTest->Text + "*'";
    }
    if (!String::IsNullOrEmpty(textBox_SearchClassStroy->Text)) {
        Query += searchCondition + " Класс_строя LIKE '*" + textBox_SearchClassStroy->Text + "*'";
    }
    if (!String::IsNullOrEmpty(textBox_SearchKolvoSekciy->Text)) {
        Query += searchCondition + " Количество_секций LIKE '*" + textBox_SearchKolvoSekciy->Text + "*'";
    }
    if (!String::IsNullOrEmpty(textBox_SearchVesUdilisha->Text)) {
        Query += searchCondition + " Вес_удилища LIKE '*" + textBox_SearchVesUdilisha->Text + "*'";
    }
    if (!String::IsNullOrEmpty(textBox_SearchTypeKolec->Text)) {
        Query += searchCondition + " Тип_колец LIKE '*" + textBox_SearchTypeKolec->Text + "*'";
    }
    if (!String::IsNullOrEmpty(textBox_SearchRukoytka->Text)) {
        Query += searchCondition + " Рукоятка LIKE '*" + textBox_SearchRukoytka->Text + "*'";
    }
    if (!String::IsNullOrEmpty(textBox_SearchKatushkoDzerz->Text)) {
        Query += searchCondition + " Катушкодержатели LIKE '*" + textBox_SearchKatushkoDzerz->Text + "*'";
    }
    if (!String::IsNullOrEmpty(textBox_SearchBrend->Text)) {
        Query += searchCondition + " Бренд LIKE '*" + textBox_SearchBrend->Text + "*'";
    }

    // Удаляем начальное "1=1" если были добавлены условия
    if (Query != "SELECT * FROM [FDProg] WHERE 1=1") {
        Query = Query->Replace("WHERE 1=1" + searchCondition, "WHERE ");
    }

    OleDbCommand^ dbCommand = gcnew OleDbCommand(Query, dbConnection);
    OleDbDataAdapter^ dataAdapter = gcnew OleDbDataAdapter();
    dataAdapter->SelectCommand = dbCommand;
    DataTable^ dataTable = gcnew DataTable();
    dataAdapter->Fill(dataTable);
    dataGridView1->DataSource = dataTable;
    dataGridView1->Refresh();
    dbConnection->Close();
}

Не работает тут, при нажатии кнопки datagridview пустой, но данные из текстбоксов правильные, вроде все перерыл, решения не нашёл

Добро пожаловать на сайт ru.SO!  Прежде чем спрашивать «почему у меня не работает вот этот (простыня из тысячи строк) код?» постарайтесь сами локализовать проблему, выделить минимальный фрагмент кода, на котором, как вы считаете возникает проблема. Прочитайте о том Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример => https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example также как задать хороший вопрос => https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Решайте проблему по шагам. Запрос без условий SELECT * FROM [FDProg] хоть что-то возвращает? Если да, то добавляйте условия по одному и снова проверяйте.

Судя по названиям, многие параметры являются числами. Для их ввода вместо текстбоксов лучше использовать NumericUpDown.

Кстати, какой тип колонок в БД у числовых параметров? Если numeric, то LIKE на них работать не будет.
